# How to GROUP BY same strings in Java

Tags: java

I have got an Arraylist of strings and I need to return the Arraylist indexes of strings that are the same.

For example

```
Arraylist[0]: IPAddress

Arraylist[1]: DomainName

Arraylist[2]: IPAddress

Arraylist[3]: Filesize
```

The output should be:

```
Arraylist[0]
IPAddress|0,2 //0,2 denotes the arraylist index that is of the same

Arraylist[1]
DomainName|1

Arraylist[2]
Filesize|3
```

Any idea how can this be achieved?

What I have done is:

```
for(int i=0; i<arr.size(); i++){
   if(arr.get(i).equals(arr.size()-1)){
      //print index


   }
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to use List instead a map?

HashMap<String,List<String>>.. You can achieve using this datastructure

Comment: Have you search about sorting and search algorithms?

Comment: Can you provide code for me to reference? I cant seem to solve my problem after trying out my logic...

Comment: That looks like a homework dump to me. But I agree with @ShreyasSarvothama, except that it should be `Map<String, List<Integer>>`.

Comment: @Shawn What logic? You haven't shown any. Edit the question and add the code you do have, and we'll help out.

Comment: I have no experience in the Map class. any idea how can I get out the indexes of the same strings?

Comment: @Andreas They also have Domain name, etc etc.. so it would be better as a String isnt it?

Comment: @Shawn Dear Friend, I would advise you to work on some examples and try out this.. Even after you trying out nothing happens.. SO community will definitely help out..

Comment: Not having experience is not an excuse for not learning something new.

Comment: @ShreyasSarvothama As example, the map key would be `IPAddress`, and the value list would be `[0, 2]`. Not sure what data types OP is expecting the output to be, so the result could be a simple `ArrayList<String>` with values like `"IPAddress|0,2"` created from that map entry.

Comment: @Andreas oh.. I confused then.. I thought he wants to prints the IP Addresses in those index.. My Bad.. then it should be Integer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With Java8 streams

```
    List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("IPAddress", "DomainName", "IPAddress", "Filesize");
    Map<String, List<Integer>> map = IntStream.range(0, strings.size()).boxed().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(strings::get));
    System.out.println(map);
```

output

```
{DomainName=[1], Filesize=[3], IPAddress=[0, 2]}
```

To get the results in ordered

```
    Map<String, List<Integer>> map = IntStream.range(0, strings.size())
                                    .boxed()
                                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(strings::get, LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.toList()));
```

Answer (score 0):

The mechanical steps are fairly straightforward:

- Get a collection which can support a key (which is the string in your list) and a list of values representing the indexes in which they occur (which would be another `ArrayList`).
- If the element exists in the collection, simply add the index to its value.
- Otherwise, create a new list, add the index to that, then add that to the collection.

Here is some sample code below.

```
final List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>() {{
    add("IPAddress");
    add("DomainName");
    add("IPAddress");
    add("Filesize");
}};

final Map<String, List<Integer>> correlations = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    final String key = list.get(i);
    if (correlations.containsKey(key)) {
        correlations.get(key).add(i);
    } else {
        final List<Integer> indexList = new ArrayList<>();
        indexList.add(i);
        correlations.put(key, indexList);
    }
}
```

Any optimizations to the above are left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: `new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("IPAddress", "DomainName", "IPAddress", "Filesize"))` would be better than creating an entire new anonymous class just for seed the list.

Comment: @Andreas:  Probably, but I'm going to assume that the seed information comes from somewhere else.  That was only there as an example; it's not the focus of the solution.

Comment: For that, the entire 8-line content of the loop can be this simple: `correlations.computeIfAbsent(list.get(i), k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(i)`